# Europecv: how to add personal website link in personal info?

Tags: pdftex, europecv

I can use `\ecvname`, `\ecvemail`, etc... but what if I want to insert my personal website URL together with the other info (preferably below my email address)? I've found the `\ecvhomepage` command but it doesn't do anything.

Example:

```
\ecvname{Al Zuhouri Ramy}
\ecvaddress{My Adress}
\ecvtelephone{My Phone Number}
\ecvfax{My Fax}
\ecvemail{My Email}
\ecvhomepage{My Website URL}     % This doesn't do anything
\ecvnationality{Italiana}
\ecvdateofbirth{06/10/1989}
\ecvgender{Maschile}
```

I'm trying to understand if there is some specific command, or if there is a way to insert a custom element (e.g. like the `\ecvitem` command, but outside the `europecv` environment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update your used document class. The up-to-date class for an Europass CV is `europecv2013`, see [Github for europecv2013](https://github.com/leinardi/europecv2013).

With it the following MWE with command ``` \ecvhomepage{\href{Homepage URL}{Homepage URL without ``http://''}} ``` compiles without problems:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,english,logo,notitle,totpages,utf8]{europecv2013}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ecvname{Replace with First name(s) Surname(s)}
\ecvaddress{Replace with house number, street name, city, postcode, country}
\ecvtelephone[Replace with telephone number]{Replace with mobile number}
\ecvemail{State e-mail address}
\ecvhomepage{\href{Homepage URL}{Homepage URL without ``http://''}}
\ecvlinkedin{\href{LinkedIn public profile URL}{LinkedIn public profile URL without ``http://''}}
\ecvgender{Enter sex}
\ecvdateofbirth{dd/mm/yyyy}
\ecvnationality{Enter nationality/-ies}

\ecvfootnote{© European Union, 2002-2015 | http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu}
%\ecvbeforepicture{\raggedleft}
%\ecvpicture[width=2.5cm]{file-immagine-eps}
%\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{-37mm}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[10pt]

\ecvposition{Job applied for
Position
Preferred kob
Studies applied for}{Replace with job applied for / position / preferred job / studies applied for (delete non relevant headings in left column)}

\ecvsection{Work experience}
%[Add separate entries for each experience. Start from the most recent.]

\ecvworkexperience{Replace with dates (from - to)}{Replace with occupation or position held}{Replace with employer’s name}{Replace with employer’s locality (if relevant, full address and website)}{Replace with main activities and responsibilities}

\ecvsection{Education and training}
%[Add separate entries for each course. Start from the most recent.]

\ecveducation{Replace with dates (from - to)}{Replace with qualification awarded}{Replace with education or training organisation’s name and locality (if relevant, country)}{
Replace with a list of principal subjects covered or skills acquired}{Replace with EQF (or other) level if relevant}

\ecvsection{Personal skills}

\ecvmothertongue[20pt]{Replace with mother tongue(s)}
\ecvlanguageheader
\ecvlanguage{Replace with language}{Enter level}{Enter level}{Enter level}{Enter level}{Enter level}
\ecvlastlanguage{Replace with language}{\ecvCTwo}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvBOne}{\ecvATwo}
\ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]

\ecvitem[5pt]{Language(s) certificates}{}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\textbf{English}}{Blafasel, Total score: 333, date: 2015-10-21}

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

and gives you the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

If you do not want to change the version you have to add the following code to your cv:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ecv@homepagekey{\ecv@utf{Homepage}} % <================================
\renewcommand{\ecvpersonalinfo}[1][0pt]{% <=================================
& \tabularnewline
\ifx\@empty\ecvdrawpicture\else
   &\ecv@beforepic\ecvdrawpicture\ecv@afterpic\tabularnewline
\fi
{\large\par\textbf{\ecv@infosectionkey}} & \tabularnewline
& \tabularnewline
\ecv@namekey & \large\textbf{\ecv@name}\tabularnewline[5pt]
\ifx\@empty\ecv@address\else
\ecv@addresskey     &\ecv@address   \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@telephone\else
\ecv@telkey         &\ecv@telephone
 \ifx\@empty\ecv@mobile\else\qquad\ecv@mobilekey: \ecv@mobile\fi
\tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@fax\else
\ecv@faxkey         &\ecv@fax \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@email\else
\ecv@emailkey       &\ecv@email \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@homepage\else % <========================================
\ecv@homepagekey       &\ecv@homepage \tabularnewline[5pt] % <===========
\fi % <==================================================================
\ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality\else
\ecv@nationalitykey & \ecv@nationality \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@birth\else
\ecv@birthkey       & \ecv@birth \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@gender\else
\ecv@genderkey      & \ecv@gender \tabularnewline[#1]
\fi
}
\makeatother
```

With the following MWE for class `europecv`

```
\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,totpages]{europecv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{url}


\makeatletter
\def\ecv@homepagekey{\ecv@utf{Homepage}}
\renewcommand{\ecvpersonalinfo}[1][0pt]{%
& \tabularnewline
\ifx\@empty\ecvdrawpicture\else
   &\ecv@beforepic\ecvdrawpicture\ecv@afterpic\tabularnewline
\fi
{\large\par\textbf{\ecv@infosectionkey}} & \tabularnewline
& \tabularnewline
\ecv@namekey & \large\textbf{\ecv@name}\tabularnewline[5pt]
\ifx\@empty\ecv@address\else
\ecv@addresskey     &\ecv@address   \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@telephone\else
\ecv@telkey         &\ecv@telephone
 \ifx\@empty\ecv@mobile\else\qquad\ecv@mobilekey: \ecv@mobile\fi
\tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@fax\else
\ecv@faxkey         &\ecv@fax \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@email\else
\ecv@emailkey       &\ecv@email \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@homepage\else
\ecv@homepagekey       &\ecv@homepage \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality\else
\ecv@nationalitykey & \ecv@nationality \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@birth\else
\ecv@birthkey       & \ecv@birth \tabularnewline[5pt]
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@gender\else
\ecv@genderkey      & \ecv@gender \tabularnewline[#1]
\fi
}
\makeatother


\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{phv} % Uses Helvetica instead of fixed width font

\ecvname{Surname, Name}
\ecvfootername{Name Surname}
\ecvaddress{House number, street name, postcode, city, country}
\ecvtelephone[(Remove if not relevant)]{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvfax{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvemail{\url{email@address.com} (Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvhomepage{\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}}
\ecvnationality{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvdateofbirth{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvgender{(Remove if not relevant)}
%\ecvpicture[width=2cm]{mypicture}
\ecvfootnote{For more information go to \url{http://europass.cedefop.eu.int}\\
\textcopyright~European Communities, 2003.}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}


\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]
\ecvitem{\large\textbf{Desired employment/ Occupational~field}}{\large\textbf{(Remove if not relevant)}}

\ecvsection{Work experience}
\ecvitem{Dates}{Add separate entries for each relevant post occupied, starting from the most recent. (Remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Main activities and responsibilities}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Name and address of employer}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Type of business or sector}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Education and training}

\ecvitem{Dates}{Add separate entries for each relevant course you have completed, starting from the most recent. (Remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{Title of qualification awarded}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Principal subjects/Occupational skills covered}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Name and type of organization providing education and training}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Level in national or international classification\footnote{If appropriate.}}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Personal skills and~competences}

\ecvmothertongue[5pt]{Specify mother tongue}
\ecvitem{\large Other language(s)}{}
%\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
\ecvlanguage{Language}{}{}{}{}{}
\ecvlanguage{Language}{}{}{}{}{}
\ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]{(*)}

\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Social skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Organisational skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Technical skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Computer skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Artistic skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{\large Driving licence(s)}{State here whether you hold a driving licence and if so for which categories of vehicle. (Remove if not relevant).}

\ecvsection{Additional information}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{Include here any other information that may be relevant, for example contact persons, references, etc. (Remove heading if not relevant).}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{publications}
\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Publications}}
\ecvitem{}{\bibentry{pub1}}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{\bibentry{pub2}}
\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Personal interests}}
\ecvitem{}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Annexes}
\ecvitem{}{List any item attached to the CV}
\end{europecv}


\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting cv]